# How to send data to another server and save the response via socket

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to send data to a server `AAA` and get the response then save it to my model.

My client is an a infinite loop,

Because I'm afraid the client will miss the response of the server after sending request.

What's the better way to save the response of  `AAA` into my Rails model ?

```
Thread.new {
    while true
      p "Client:#{ssl_socket.gets}"        
    end
}

while true
  sleep(0.5)
  send_data(ssl_socket, content)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of that true assertion in while loop, you need to determine if to send request again or not. You can determine that from the data received

E.G.

```
send_again = true

Thread.new {
    while send_again
      p "Client:#{ssl_socket.gets}"
      send_again = false if #data successfully received
    end
}

while send_again
  sleep(0.5)
  send_data(ssl_socket, content)
end
```

You should also consider setting `max_limit` variable and send the data only if `sent_count`  is less than `max_limit`. If the `max_limit` is reached you should log it or raise exception.

Comment: You need to tweak this logic a bit to adjust your need.